# Apply function element wise to list of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, max, sapply

I have a list of matrices/dataframes , for example:

```
mat = list(matrix(1:6,2,3),matrix(5:10,2,3),matrix(4:9,2,3))
mat
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    9
[2,]    6    8   10

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    6    8
[2,]    5    7    9
```

I want to get max elementwise from each matrix.

```
a= matrix(0,2,3)
for(i in 1:2){
  for(j in 1:3){
    a[i,j] = max(sapply(mat,function(x){x[i,j]}))
  }
}
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    9
[2,]    6    8   10
```

This gives me the desired output but is there any way it can be done without for loop?

Answer (score 6):

An option with `Reduce` and `pmax`:

```r
Reduce(pmax, mat)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    7    9
#[2,]    6    8   10
```

Or, with `purrr::reduce`:

```r
purrr::reduce(mat, pmax)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    7    9
#[2,]    6    8   10
```

Answer (score 5):

```
apply(simplify2array(mat), c(1,2), max)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    7    9
#[2,]    6    8   10
```

Answer (score 5):

We could use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, mat)
```

-output

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    9
[2,]    6    8   10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a <- array(unlist(mat), dim=c(2,3,3))
apply(a, c(1,2), max)
```